# I need a good Limma tutorial that uses R

Tags: r, bioconductor, limma

I'm trying to get started using some statistical analysis with the limma package that runs out of R. Any one know a good tutorial?

Answer (score 6):

The limma [web-page](http://bioinf.wehi.edu.au/limma/) has plenty of material. I've also written a [tutorial paper](http://www.mas.ncl.ac.uk/~ncsg3/microarray/) that analyses yeast microarray data using (amongst other things) limma.

Comment: Cool thanks....so the problem that I'm having now is my data is Agilent not affymetric. Any workarounds for this>?

Comment: @illbill: I would try asking that question at [biostar](http://biostar.stackexchange.com/)